# Can typed-switched B cells recognize the tertiary structure of antigens?

Tags: immunology, antibody, antigen, immunoglobin

As T helper cells are responsible for isotype switching but Th cells are MHC class 2 restricted and MHC only presents denatured peptides (up to 30 residues, no folding), does that imply that only IgM can recognize tertiary structure? If IgG and the like can, how was that naive b-cell able to present a tertiary structure recognizable by a Th and thus typed-switched.

Comment: MHC and B cell receptors/antibodies are totally different things, and recognize completely independent antigens. I think you're mixing up the two.

Comment: But doesn't it take a Th cell specific to the same antibody as a B cell to cause the B cell to type switch? And the Th is immune restricted to class II MHC.

Comment: Th cells are not "*specific to the same antibody*" as B cells because T cells don't care about antibody/BCR recognition sites. B cells are activated by Th cells that recognize the same *antigen* (a protein, for example), but not the same *epitope*. BCRs/antibodies and MHC (I or II) have very different epitopes. A B cells Class II doesn't necessarily display the same peptide its BCR recognizes.

Comment: Sorry, meant antigen, typo.. how does the Th cell know it recognizes the same antigen as the B cell (or vice versa)?

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that b cells endocytos BCR-bound antigens and present on MHC class 2.. makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B cells endocytos BCR-bound antigens and present them on class II MHC. Previously activated Th cells then activate the B cell.

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide explanation, context, and include references to reliable sources. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right with appropriate citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed. Please take the [tour] and then consult the [help] pages for additional advice on [Answer] (and [Ask]) effectively on this site and then delete or [edit] your answer (and question) accordingly.